# Formatting if-else in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

is there any way to format `if-else` statement in Eclipse where multiple conditions come in each line while pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>?
I tried to fiddle around in `Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter`, but was not able to find the right option to get it working.

The format that i am trying to achieve is as follows.

```
if(condition1 == true
       && condition2 == true
       && condition3 == true
       && condition4 == true
       && condition5 == true) {
    return 0;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

May be your requirement adjusted in below confirguration.

Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter -> Edit

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Strict every condition in parenthesis , it will work .

Answer (score 0):

Sadly you can't do what you want using Code Style -> Formatter, but yes, writing in parenthesis will work.